# drupal block visibility when a field is > 0

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, block

I have a content type `event` containing a field called `number_vip_pass`. An event has 20 vip pass and the number of vip pass decreases when someone takes one (via rules).
The problem is that, actually, users can take vip pass even when `number_vip_pass = 0`. It makes the value of this field go negative.

I would like to hide the block (called `vip_pass`) allowing people to take pass when `number_vip_pass < 1` and I've found that you can hide it with the 'Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE' checkbox.

**My question is :** What PHP code should I put in there? I tried different ways to write this script but can't find the answer. I don't know how to get the field to compare it to 1 in the if statement.

**Here is my code :**

```
if(arg(0) == 'node')
{
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $nid));
  if ($node->field_number_vip_pass < 1)
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
  else
  {
     return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Have a nice day =)

Ok so I've found the answer on the net :

```
$node  = menu_get_object();

return (isset($node->field_number_vip_pass[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) ? $node->field_nbre_pass_vip[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : FALSE;
```

I don't know why, I don't know how, but this works perfectly.

Comment: That type of field is field_number_vip_pass? For example if it's an input field, the correct code is $node->field_number_vip_pass['und'][0]['value']. You should debug your $node variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to change the code to be something like

```
if (count($node->field_number_vip_pass[LANGUAGE_NONE]) < 1)
{
   return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave me some clues to find the answer.